# ¿Por qué no se usa el subjuntivo en preposiciones del futuro cuando el verbo está en una pregunta?

Tags: subjuntivo

He notado (por mi cuenta) que las preguntas sobre hechos futuros sólo usan el indicativo. Ejemplo:

> "Bueno... todo esto suena muy sospechoso, pero no te preocupes. Oye,
>   ¿**cuándo vuelves**?"

Y también:

> Hola, Julio. Soy Manuela. Mira, tengo una foto maravillosa de Javier
>   Bardo. No de la entrevista. En la calle. Una foto fantástica.
>   -Excelente. **¿Cuándo la traes?**

¿Hay una razón, regla o explicación?

Comment: Es curioso, no me habia dado cuenta de que el subjuntivo no tiene sentido como verbo principal de una oración, aunque si se puede usar en subordinadas: "¿me puedes llamar **cuando llegues**?"

Comment: @Brian H. ah, asi es.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El nombre del modo subjuntivo tiene de hecho que ver con el hecho de que el mismo **aparece (casi) únicamente en proposiciones subordinadas**. Notablemente, el modo equivalente en otras lenguas se llama también "conjuntivo" porque aparece siempre **junto** a otra proposición (a la cual queda subordinado).

(Es debatible el caso de oraciones desiderativas como *«Hubieras avisado antes»*, que pueden tratarse como elipsis de *«Desearía que hubieras avisado antes»*.)

No es correcto decir que el modo indicativo sea el único usado para preguntar sobre el futuro. Sí es correcto decir que se usa el presente de indicativo para preguntar **sobre un futuro que se presupone que ocurrirá con certeza**: *«¿Cuándo vuelves?»* (implica o sugiere que vas a volver, con total seguridad, a cierta hora). O bien *«¿Cuándo la traes?»*, que sugiere que vas a traerme la foto (que no te negarás a traerla y que lo harás en algún momento definido del futuro).

El futuro simple del indicativo también puede aparecer en esta clase de preguntas, pero muchas veces se utiliza con valor de incertidumbre o [probabilidad](http://hispanoteca.eu/Lexikon%20der%20Linguistik/f/FUTURO%20DE%20PROBABILIDAD.htm): *«¿Cuándo volverás?»* (que yo escucharía como «tengo dudas de que vayas a volver, necesito que me digas aproximadamente cuándo vas a volver»).

También se puede usar el condicional, con o sin condición explícita: *«¿Cuándo volverías (si salieras ahora mismo)?»*. O en el segundo ejemplo: *«¿Cuándo la traerías (si te la pidiera)?»*. En este caso se está preguntando por un futuro que depende de otras cosas.